# Rank of the sum of two full rank matrices

Tags: matrices

I have two full rank matrices $A$ and $B$. Is there any proof that show

1. $Rank(A + B) = Rank(A) + Rank(B)$
2. $Rank(A + B) \geq \min(Rank(A), Rank(B))$
3. $Rank(A + B) = \max(Rank(A) , Rank(B))$

Comment: Consider $I_n$ and $-I_n$

Comment: None of those relations is true in the general case

Answer (score 2):

No. Here is the easiest counterexamples I could find:

$$A=-B\neq 0$$